# comparing two maps values with correspond to key

Tags: java, dictionary

I have the following two different map's as shown below..

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> multimap1 = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
List<String> someList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
someList1.add("abc");
someList1.add("def");
someList1.add("ght");
multimap1.put(1, someList1);
```

and the other is..

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> multimap2 = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
someList2.add("abc");
someList2.add("wed");
someList2.add("ght");
multimap2.put(1, someList2);
```

Now please advise the logic as I want to compare the values of both the maps with correspond to key that first i take the key from first map that is from multimap1 and will also take the first key from multimap2 and then will compare their values that is

```
multimap1       multimap2

1   abc         1  abc
```

as shown above i have taken the key of both the map and then compare the values corresponding to key so it matches as both the different map having the same values correspond to first key so it should print the statement on console that both the maps have same value with correspond to key and if it is not then it should print both the maps have different values correspond to keys,, Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: Shouldn't 1 map to "abc,def,ght" and "abc,wed,ght", respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is a bit confusing, the value at key 1 for both maps is the List.

```
multimap1       multimap2

1   abc         1  abc
```

is not correct as these are not the values of the map with their key being 1, it is only part of the value as the rest of the strings in the list is also part of the value.

If you're comparing the values of two lists, it depends a bit on what would mean by them being equal. If they have to have the same values in the same order, then just check index by index of the two lists. If they only have to have the same values and the order does not matter, then check if all elements of one is in the other and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

How to do this with Guava:

1. Use `Sets.symmetricDifference()` or `Sets.difference()` to find the difference between keys. `Sets.intersection()` to find common keys.
2. Iterate over the common keys if symmetric difference is empty. Wrap lists into `HashSet`s or `LinkedHashSet`s if order matters and apply `Sets.difference()` to the wrapped sets.